# Use string streams instead of file streams in svm-predict command

Tags: c++, opencv, printf, libsvm

i want to use string streams in memory instead of a file stream to read in the file from disk for performance purposes. the parameters for svm-predict is: ./svm-predict test_file model_file output_file. Here is my code (using libsvm):

Where poseData is the string stream that contains the same input svm values as the working flat file version.

```
char temp[5120000];
char temp2[512];
sprintf(temp2, "./svm-predict %s %s %s", (FILE *)poseData, "tmp_train.model", (FILE*)temp );
// sprintf(temp2, "./svm-predict %s%i%s %s %s%i%s", "./Test_Files/", pos,".jpg.txt","tmp_train.model", "./Output/",pos,".jpg.output");
```

The commented out version of sprintf works, but is slow because of hard drive access. also the sprintf poseData looks exactly like the flat file but i cannot cast it to one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[svm-predict](http://www.moleberry.com/man/s/svm-predict.1.html) takes file system locations for data and models (this is why your first attempt works). You can't pass memory pointers to the external program.

You'll need to use either the `libsvm` library, or OpenCV has [CvSVM](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html?highlight=svm#CvSVM) that you might try using internally for performance. [Here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/ml/table_of_content_ml/table_of_content_ml.html) are a couple of tutorials on use SVM in OpenCV. OpenCV's SVM implementation is based on LibSVM, so that's probably what I would use since you are already using OpenCV anyway.

Comment: Oh i forgot to say.. I need to compare the performance of svm's using cuda vs cpu. i was planning on using libsvm vs cusvm